# Implement CustomError and Default Error combined in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my web.config, I am using the below code:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound/"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/InternalServerError/"/>
</customErrors>
```

But, In my controller actionmethod I am explicitly throwing an error and want to redirect the application to some other default Error page. Below is the code

```
[HandleError(View = "Error")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception();
        return View();
    }
```

**I want the application should redirect to Error page. But, its always redirecting to NotFound page.**

Comment: The status codes might be the reason here.

Comment: @Coding - there is no error, but the NotFound View is loading on ActionMethod exception but I want Error View to be displayed

Comment: try changing the web.config just to:  `<customErrors mode="On" />`

Comment: @Coding - but how the reference pages of NotFound and InternalServerError would be called then ?

Comment: OK which IIS version are you using

Comment: I am testing this on my machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169105/discussion-between-harshsharma-and-coding).

Comment: Double check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Coding - yes it worked well, thanks.